# Why are PROPS and their morphisms strict?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, monoidal-categories

According to both [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PROP) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROP_(category_theory)), PROPS are defined as special kinds of **strict** symmetric monoidal categories and morphisms between them are defined as **strict** symmetric monoidal functors. Why is strictness required? I can understand requiring the categories to be strict since every symmetric monoidal category is equivalent to a strict one. So strictness can make working with them easier. But requiring the functors to be **strict** seems unnatural. Is there a conceptual reason for requiring the functors to be strict?